# Bootstrap: prevent jumbotron to resize to minimum before content is updated

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, twitter-bootstrap-3, frontend

for a freecodecamp challenge I implemented a simple random quote page, using a bootstrap 4 jumbotron. Now my problem is when I click the button to get a new quote, the jumbotron area become empty and resizes to minimum, then is filled with the new quote and reach the final correct size. I would like the jumbotron change its size accordingly to the content without passing through that intermediate state. This is my page:

https://codepen.io/bui3/full/qVGGNw/

And this is like I want

https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/ONjoLe

```
[Here][1] my page, and [here][2] what I would like.
```

Hope somebody can help me.
Thank you

Comment: Please share what you have tried / your code on jsfiddle and link it in the question.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Sorry, I had problems with links. I changed my message with working links

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I managed to solve this issue by myself